# CMake find_package Project Name Case

Tags: c++, cmake

I am messing around with importing/exporting CMake packages and came across something I cannot figure out. I have two libraries, *lib1* and *lib2* and the following folder structure

```
project/
├─ lib1/
│  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  ├─ include/
│  │  ├─ lib1/
│  │  │  ├─ lib1.hpp
│  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ lib1.cpp
├─ lib2/
│  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  ├─ include/
│  │  ├─ lib2/
│  │  │  ├─ lib2.hpp
│  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ lib2.cpp
```

I have the following *CMakeLists.txt* files

```
###################################################################################################
# LIBRARY CREATION
###################################################################################################
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

project(lib1 VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX d)
include(GNUInstallDirs)

# collect private library headers and implementation files
file(GLOB LIBRARY_SOURCES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*)

# add library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBRARY_SOURCES})

# public header file usage for library
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
                           $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/${PROJECT_NAME}>
                           $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}>)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
                           $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
                           $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>)

# specify compile requirements
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
###################################################################################################

###################################################################################################
# LIBRARY INSTALLATION
###################################################################################################
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

# install library and create export form specifying build artifact installation locations
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}_Targets
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
        INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})

# install public headers
install(DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/${PROJECT_NAME}
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})

# install cmake file specifying installation targets
install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}_Targets
        FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets.cmake
        NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME})

# create version file for cmake project
write_basic_package_version_file(${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake
                                  VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
                                  COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion)

# create config file for cmake project
configure_package_config_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake.in
                              ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake
                              INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME})

# install cmake project config files
install(FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake
              ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}/)
###################################################################################################
```

```
###################################################################################################
# LIBRARY CREATION
###################################################################################################
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

project(lib2 VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX d)
include(GNUInstallDirs)

# collect private library headers and implementation files
file(GLOB LIBRARY_SOURCES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*)

# add library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBRARY_SOURCES})

# public header file usage for library
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
                           $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/${PROJECT_NAME}>
                           $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}>)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
                           $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
                           $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>)

# specify compile requirements
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC cxx_std_11)

# link library 1
find_package(lib1 CONFIG REQUIRED
             COMPONENTS lib1)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} lib1::lib1)
###################################################################################################

###################################################################################################
# LIBRARY INSTALLATION
###################################################################################################
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

# install library and create export form specifying build artifact installation locations
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}_Targets
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
        INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})

# install public headers
install(DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/${PROJECT_NAME}
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})

# install cmake file specifying installation targets
install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}_Targets
        FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets.cmake
        NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME})

# create version file for cmake project
write_basic_package_version_file(${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake
                                  VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
                                  COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion)

# create config file for cmake project
configure_package_config_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake.in
                              ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake
                              INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME})

# install cmake project config files
install(FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake
              ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}/)
###################################################################################################
```

and I run the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

INSTALL_DIR=$PWD/install
mkdir -p ${INSTALL_DIR}

pushd lib1
mkdir -p build
pushd build

cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${INSTALL_DIR}/lib1 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
make install

popd
popd

pushd lib2
mkdir -p build
pushd build

cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${INSTALL_DIR}/lib2 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${INSTALL_DIR}
make install

popd
popd
```

I noticed that if I use "lib1" in the *find_package* call in CMakeLists.txt for lib2, I get the following error

> Make Error at CMakeLists.txt:29 (find_package):
> Found package configuration file:
> /project/install/lib1/lib/cmake/lib1/lib1Config.cmake
> but it set lib1_FOUND to FALSE so package "lib1" is considered to be NOT
> FOUND.

while using "LIB1" results in successful compilation. Anyone know why this is?

**UPDATE 04/21/2022**

Contents of *lib1Config.cmake.in*

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/@PROJECT_NAME@Targets.cmake")
check_required_components("@PROJECT_NAME@")
```

Contents of *lib1Config.cmake*

```
####### Expanded from @PACKAGE_INIT@ by configure_package_config_file() #######
####### Any changes to this file will be overwritten by the next CMake run ####
####### The input file was lib1Config.cmake.in                            ########

get_filename_component(PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../" ABSOLUTE)

macro(set_and_check _var _file)
  set(${_var} "${_file}")
  if(NOT EXISTS "${_file}")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "File or directory ${_file} referenced by variable ${_var} does not exist !")
  endif()
endmacro()

macro(check_required_components _NAME)
  foreach(comp ${${_NAME}_FIND_COMPONENTS})
    if(NOT ${_NAME}_${comp}_FOUND)
      if(${_NAME}_FIND_REQUIRED_${comp})
        set(${_NAME}_FOUND FALSE)
      endif()
    endif()
  endforeach()
endmacro()

####################################################################################
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib1Targets.cmake")
check_required_components("lib1")
```

Contents of *lib1Targets.cmake*

```
# Generated by CMake

if("${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}" LESS 2.5)
   message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake >= 2.6.0 required")
endif()
cmake_policy(PUSH)
cmake_policy(VERSION 2.6...3.19)
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated CMake target import file.
#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Commands may need to know the format version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION 1)

# Protect against multiple inclusion, which would fail when already imported targets are added once more.
set(_targetsDefined)
set(_targetsNotDefined)
set(_expectedTargets)
foreach(_expectedTarget lib1::lib1_static lib1::lib1_shared)
  list(APPEND _expectedTargets ${_expectedTarget})
  if(NOT TARGET ${_expectedTarget})
    list(APPEND _targetsNotDefined ${_expectedTarget})
  endif()
  if(TARGET ${_expectedTarget})
    list(APPEND _targetsDefined ${_expectedTarget})
  endif()
endforeach()
if("${_targetsDefined}" STREQUAL "${_expectedTargets}")
  unset(_targetsDefined)
  unset(_targetsNotDefined)
  unset(_expectedTargets)
  set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION)
  cmake_policy(POP)
  return()
endif()
if(NOT "${_targetsDefined}" STREQUAL "")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Some (but not all) targets in this export set were already defined.\nTargets Defined: ${_targetsDefined}\nTargets not yet defined: ${_targetsNotDefined}\n")
endif()
unset(_targetsDefined)
unset(_targetsNotDefined)
unset(_expectedTargets)


# Compute the installation prefix relative to this file.
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)
if(_IMPORT_PREFIX STREQUAL "/")
  set(_IMPORT_PREFIX "")
endif()

# Create imported target lib1::lib1_static
add_library(lib1::lib1_static STATIC IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(lib1::lib1_static PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_COMPILE_FEATURES "cxx_std_11"
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include;${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include"
)

# Create imported target lib1::lib1_shared
add_library(lib1::lib1_shared SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(lib1::lib1_shared PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_COMPILE_FEATURES "cxx_std_11"
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include;${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include"
)

# Load information for each installed configuration.
get_filename_component(_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
file(GLOB CONFIG_FILES "${_DIR}/lib1Targets-*.cmake")
foreach(f ${CONFIG_FILES})
  include(${f})
endforeach()

# Cleanup temporary variables.
set(_IMPORT_PREFIX)

# Loop over all imported files and verify that they actually exist
foreach(target ${_IMPORT_CHECK_TARGETS} )
  foreach(file ${_IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_${target}} )
    if(NOT EXISTS "${file}" )
      message(FATAL_ERROR "The imported target \"${target}\" references the file
   \"${file}\"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}\"
but not all the files it references.
")
    endif()
  endforeach()
  unset(_IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_${target})
endforeach()
unset(_IMPORT_CHECK_TARGETS)

# This file does not depend on other imported targets which have
# been exported from the same project but in a separate export set.

# Commands beyond this point should not need to know the version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION)
cmake_policy(POP)
```

Contents of *lib1Targets-release.cmake*

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated CMake target import file for configuration "Release".
#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Commands may need to know the format version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION 1)

# Import target "lib1::lib1_static" for configuration "Release"
set_property(TARGET lib1::lib1_static APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS RELEASE)
set_target_properties(lib1::lib1_static PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES_RELEASE "CXX"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/liblib1_static.a"
  )

list(APPEND _IMPORT_CHECK_TARGETS lib1::lib1_static )
list(APPEND _IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_lib1::lib1_static "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/liblib1_static.a" )

# Import target "lib1::lib1_shared" for configuration "Release"
set_property(TARGET lib1::lib1_shared APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS RELEASE)
set_target_properties(lib1::lib1_shared PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/liblib1_shared.dylib"
  IMPORTED_SONAME_RELEASE "@rpath/liblib1_shared.dylib"
  )

list(APPEND _IMPORT_CHECK_TARGETS lib1::lib1_shared )
list(APPEND _IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_lib1::lib1_shared "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/liblib1_shared.dylib" )

# Commands beyond this point should not need to know the version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION)
```

Comment: What is content of `lib1Config.cmake` file? You create it with `configure_package_config_file`, but it is just a template substitution, and it is you who provide template for it (`lib1Config.cmake.in`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for joining in. I added the contents of the autogenerated CMake files.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is emitted because not all COMPONENTS has been found. Take a look into `find_package` call:

```
find_package(lib1 CONFIG REQUIRED
             COMPONENTS lib1)
```

It requests `lib1` **component**, but your config script (`lib1Config.cmake`) doesn't process it. The call to macro

```
check_required_components("@PROJECT_NAME@")
```

detects this situation and reports that whole package is not found.

Your package can be successfully found with the call

```
find_package(lib1 CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

Note, that supporting of package's components is optional. If you want to do that, then follow corresponding guide. E.g. [the one provided with CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/importing-exporting/index.html#adding-components).

Comment: Yes the components are not found with "lib1" in the find_package call but they are found with "LIB1" in the find_package call and I was wondering why a different case of the package name is required.